# Stretch image view up to the screen sides (without margins)

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Good Day!
How can I achieve the look of the first screen? I wanted to stretch an image view up to the edge of the screen but I all I get is an image view with margins on the sides. Here is my xml code:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="240dp"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_image"
 tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide your code and the .xml of the layout you are using for better understanding your problem ?

Comment: <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_image"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />                                       i just placed a simple image view. i just wanted to stretch the image until it reaches the sides of the screen. it just seems impossible. i also used constraint layout.

Comment: please add this to your post so i shows in correct formatting for everyone to help ;)

Comment: your image view width is wrap content that means it would take the place it needs not the whole width of your screen

Comment: does the parent of your image view have any padding or margins ?

Comment: Yes! I turned all of the layout's padding and margins to 0dp :D

Answer (score 0):

generally to achieve what you want to stretch the ImageView's width your layout.xml should look like this :

the parent layout of your imageView should not have any **margin** and **padding** on *left* or *right*
and its **width** should be **match_parent**

and your image view should not have any **margin** on *left* or *right* and its **width** should be **match_parent** too.

for example you have your ImageView inside an LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          ...
          android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

marginLeft or marginRight = 0dp could be removed just added them so could point that you should not have margins

hope this helps.

Comment: This may not be the exact answer but it helped me figure out what the problem is! Thank you so much! :D